# Rails ActiveRecord How to get array of associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.0.1 and I would like to get the array of associated models. That is, I have the following models and associations:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And I would like to get the array of associated models likes following.

```
Post.has_many_associated
=> [:comments, :likes]
```

Any Idea?

Thank you for your advice.

Tae-ho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_all_associations):

```
Post.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name)
```